# Why would we use extensions?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I've just learned about extensions and I was wondering, there was an example about extending a protocol. For example, let's say we have the protocol:

```
protocol CanFly {
    func canFly()
}
```

which allows all the classes who can fly to basiclly to fly. Now lets say that we use extension to extend the protocol, and we do:

```
extension CanFly {
    func canEat() {
        print("I can eat")
    }
}
```

What is the purpose of that if we can just add that `func canEat` to our protocol? More of those protocols are like an abstract struct so why would we add a func with a body to it?

- just wanna say if I've made a mess im sorry for that lol, just want to clear out few things about extension <3

Comment: it is Swift naming convention to name your functions starting with an lowercase letter

Comment: protocols are a contract that if you want that some structures will conform to it they will have to implement the methods that are present on the contract. If you extend a protocol adding a method to it, you are not requiring them to implement that function, you are providing them some functionality.

Comment: [Protocols](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html)

Comment: You may want to separate some logic and even store it in another file. That's when extensions may be helpful.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Swift documentation on [Protocol Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID521):

> Protocols can be extended to provide method, initializer, subscript,
>   and computed property implementations to conforming types. This allows
>   you to define behavior on protocols themselves, rather than in each
>   type’s individual conformance or in a global function.

This means you can run logic *within the protocol extension function* so you don't have to do it in each class that conforms to the protocol.

Personally, I also find extensions useful to extend the functionality of built-in classes like String or UIViewController since extensions can be called from anywhere in an app. I have some open-source extension [snippets](https://github.com/elliott-io/SwiftSnippets/blob/master/README.md#extensions) you can take a look at if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Extending a protocol is just one of the possible use cases for extensions, really powerful and useful, but might be confusing at the start.

I suggest you looking through [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_extensions.htm), as it dives deeper into more mundane, so to speak, ways to use it.